# xts subsetting gives incorrect results for months

Tags: r, time-series, subset, xts

I am using R 3.2.1 for Mac OS X and seem to have run into incorrect behavior in  xts subsetting. In brief, subsetting monthly data give a result that is 1 month lagged from what it should be. Here is a simple example that is similar to an analysis of paleotemperature I am doing:

First I will make some test data for the example:

```
xts.test <- xts(rnorm(440*12, mean=0, sd=10),order.by=timeBasedSeq(155001/1989))
```

This produces a correct `xts` file AFAICT. Here is the first year of 12 months.

```
head(xts.test, 12L)

               [,1]
Jan 1550 -6.9301845  
Feb 1550 12.1581413  
Mar 1550  3.9688139  
Apr 1550  3.9540268  
May 1550  9.8200923  
Jun 1550 -4.2090998  
Jul 1550  7.5950340  
Aug 1550 -6.5967389  
Sep 1550 -0.6736532  
Oct 1550  6.4939221  
Nov 1550  4.3916465  
Dec 1550 19.8800872
```

However, when I try to subset this by selecting for a single year, I get the following:

```
xts.test["1550"]

               [,1]
Feb 1550 12.1581413  
Mar 1550  3.9688139  
Apr 1550  3.9540268  
May 1550  9.8200923  
Jun 1550 -4.2090998  
Jul 1550  7.5950340  
Aug 1550 -6.5967389  
Sep 1550 -0.6736532  
Oct 1550  6.4939221  
Nov 1550  4.3916465  
Dec 1550 19.8800872  
Jan 1551 -2.9549224
```

That is, instead of the correct Jan-Dec 1550, I get Feb 1550 through Jan 1551

I get a similar lag when I try to subset by selecting months of a year. `c(2, 3,4,5,6,7)` get me April through September instead of March through August.

Any thoughts here?

Comment: Would you please set a seed with `set.seed` and desribe all the packages you have loaded by `library` or `require`? That would help to reproduce the behavior.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug that has been fixed in the most recent [development version on GitHub](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/tree/develop).

```
R> require(xts)
R> xts.test <- xts(rnorm(440*12, mean=0, sd=10),order.by=timeBasedSeq(155001/1989))
R> packageVersion("xts")
[1] ‘0.9.7’
R> str(xts.test)  # notice TZ is not set
An ‘xts’ object on Jan 1550/Dec 1989 containing:
  Data: num [1:5280, 1] -8.11 -7.65 2.07 -3.29 17.03 ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [yearmon] TZ: 
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL
```

Notice that `TZ` is not set above, but it's set in the new version below.

```
R> packageVersion("xts")
[1] ‘0.9.8’
R> str(xts.test)  # notice TZ is set
An ‘xts’ object on Jan 1550/Dec 1989 containing:
  Data: num [1:5280, 1] 0.357 12.318 24.291 22.181 6.123 ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [yearmon] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL
```

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully it will fix apply.yearly and related methods too. Can you tell me when this will be available as an installable package?

Comment: FWIW, I tried to install the current dev version of xts using R devtools. Compiling failed, however, because it has a call (unneeded??) to gfortran 4.8.

Comment: @MichaelBarton: it's needed. I assume you're on Windows; do you have [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) installed?

Comment: I'm on a Mac. It's the first time an R package has called for gfortran.

Comment: @MichaelBarton: I guess it's the first R package you've built from source that includes Fortran code...

Comment: Maybe so. But I DO have gfortran on my system. Just to be sure, I just updated it. The problem may be that the configuration or make code has hard coded a link to gfortran-4.8. I have a later version.

Comment: @MichaelBarton: It could be that, or it could be something else that's specific to OS X. Check the [OS X appendix](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#OS-X) to the R Installation and Administration manual for hints. I don't use OS X myself, nor do I have access to one, so I'm afraid I can't help more directly.

Comment: Sorry if I was not being clear. Either configuration or make makes a hard-coded call to a specific version of gfortran, an older one (gfortran 4.8).  Here is the error:  ---  
  
gfortran-4.8   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c period.max.f -o period.max.o
make: gfortran-4.8: No such file or directory ---  

I have a newer version (gfortran 5.1). I suspect that it does not matter which version I have as long as it is sufficiently new to have whatever functions are called in compiling xts. But the current code only looks for version 4.8 AFAICT.

Comment: @MichaelBarton: xts does not make any decisions regarding C or Fortran compilers. The "current code" that "only looks for version 4.8" is R itself, not xts.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: I installed gfortran 4.8 over my later version. xts still would not compile. So I had to make a symlink named gfortran-4.8 to /usr/local/bin/gfortran. Then xts compiled without issue. Unfortunately, when I loaded the newest xts (v. 0.9.874), it still has the same problem that I reported initially. So this does not seem to be fixed.